# Creating a wxActiveXContainer

Tags: c++, activex, wxwidgets

My objective is to display an active x object in wxwidgets.

I have declared two member pointers:

```
TeeChart::ITChartPtr mpChart;
wxActiveXContainer* mpAx;
```

I then create an instance of the teechart control:

```
mpChart.CreateInstance("TeeChart.TChart");
```

I then wish to create an instance of the wxActiveXContainer defined as:

```
wxActiveXContainer (wxWindow *parent, REFIID iid, IUnknown *pUnk);
```

**However, I am not sure what to pass in for the IUnknown parameter?**

Currently, I have:

```
mpAx = new wxActiveXContainer(this, __uuidof(TChart), NULL );
```

Comment: worked out the answer: `mpAx = new wxActiveXContainer(this, __uuidof(ITChart), mpChart.GetInterfacePtr());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mpAx = new wxActiveXContainer(this, __uuidof(ITChart), mpChart.GetInterfacePtr());